# How to find the exact hadoop jar command which was running my job?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie, cascading, scalding

I'm using `CDH5.4`.  I'm running a hadoop job which from command line appears to be ok (when simply running with `hadoop jar`).  However if I run it from `yarn` It finishes silently with a single mapper and no reducers.  I really suspect both 'runs' were running the same exact command. However, I want to be sure of that.  So I look at the logs at:

(note its a `scalding` job with custom runner - all is fine when I run it from command line).

`/container_1432733015407_0953_01_000001/container_1432733015407_0953_01_000001/user/stdout/?start=0`

and I saw something like:

```
Main class        : org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain

Maximum output    : 2048

Arguments         :
                    -D
                    oneparam=value
                    -D
                    secondparam=value
```

so i took these and turned into a command line.

and ran it with something like

`hadoop jar MyScaldingRunner -D oneparam=value -D secondparam=value`  and it ran just fine and produced the results.

**Is there a way for me to view the SAME EXACT `hadoop jar` command line that the hadoop was running when it was executed via `oozie` + `yarn` to run it? because from over there it just finishes silently!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have direct answer to your question but [JDiagnostics](https://github.com/shevek/jdiagnostics) could help you to recreate the parameters needed, like classpath or environment variables. Here is an [example](https://github.com/shevek/jdiagnostics#as-a-diagnostic-bundle) you can put in the beginning of your program before you run it:

```
  LOG.info(new DefaultQuery().call())
```